# Updating a flag when an attribute changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, synchronization

As part of my syncing solution, I use a `sync status` for all objects of a certain class. Whenever specific (not all) attributes of that object change, I want to update the status.

I am considering four approaches:

1. Manually setting the status in code wherever I change
   something that needs to synced. This is the most obvious, but also
   the most laborious and error-prone (I'll need to remember to also add the sync status update any time I add new functionality).
2. Track it using a core data notification (e.g. `willSave` or
   `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`). This seems the most appropriate at first glance -
   I simply sign up for the notifications in my AppDelegate and update
   the status each time. But will it be possible to examine the changes
   and only update the sync status when an attribute I care about is
   updated? Also, won't setting
   the `sync_status` itself also fires this notification, leading me into an endless loop? How would I address this?
3. Custom setters on the attributes I care about. I have had
   trouble trying to get this working before, and eventually decided
   to try to leave the standard core data getters/setters alone. But I
   would delve back in if it is the best fit.
4. KVO. I've not used this pattern before, but it might be easiest to
   just sign up for notifications of attribute changes for those I care
   about and set the flag there. But where would I do this? I need
   to monitor every object of the class, so would it be possible to start observing an
   attribute's KVO notifications in that same object's `awakeFromInsert`?
   I.e., whenever an object is created, immediately have that same
   object listen for changes to attributeA and set it's own `sync_status`
   when it fires?

Which of these approaches will serve me best? Perhaps I am missing some other ideas?

Comment: another apprach would be a protocol to notify the receiver of any changes. You could use a dictionary to transfer the relevant data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Manually setting the status code

Probably a bad idea, for exactly the reason you describe. You'll need to do this in all kinds of cases. You might not always be the developer on the app. One day you or someone else will forget it. Even if you don't, you get extra code all over the place that could be centralized.

> Track it using a core data notification [...] Also, won't setting the sync_status itself also fires this notification, leading me into an endless loop?

It depends how you do it. Listening for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` could work, if you use a secondary `NSManagedObjectContext`. That way you can set the sync flag, save changes, and avoid looping because you're saving on a different context that you're not observing.

Using `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` could also work. That will be posted when object properties are changed but a save is not actually in progress yet. Inspect the `userInfo` dictionary to see if anything you care about has changed, and if so, set your `sync_status` flag. Setting the flag would trigger a new notification, but it will be one you don't care about, so you break the loop. Using a separate context would also prevent looping here.

> Custom setters on the attributes I care about.

Definitely workable, though depending on how many attributes you care about, you could end up with a lot of accessors just to update sync status. Of the four you mention, this is the one I would use.

A related but simpler approach would be to override `willSave` on your managed object classes. That will get called just before a save. Implement it to

1. Look through `[self changedValues]` for attributes that trigger syncing.
2. Set the sync flag if you find any of them.

This way you only have one custom method per entity, no matter how many attributes end up triggering the sync flag.

> KVO

Should work, but is probably less intuitive to get working right than custom setters.

When I had to do something like this, I put the sync information outside of my data store. I'd listen for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, and in the observer method I would:

1. Look through `userInfo` to see what had changed
2. Get the `NSManagedObjectID` for each object that would need to sync
3. Convert the object IDs to NSStrings and add those to a list saved in a separate file.

On a successful sync I'd clear out the object ID list.

The thinking was mainly that a sync flag is more metadata than actual model data, so I kept it out of the model. If you prefer to keep it in the model, I'd go with overriding `willSave`.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. I am going to consider your external approach. It seems the most scalable if and when I want to sync multiple object types, and avoids having to filter the whole data set each time I want to know what to sync. Did you store the list of objects to sync in core data also? Or some other mechanism?

Comment: I put it in a property list file, which was more than adequate for the app. Convert each managed object ID to an NSString (via its URIRepresentation) and add it to the collection. I needed to treat inserts, updates, and deletes separately so I used a top-level dictionary with three keys, where the values were arrays of object IDs.

Comment: Did you ever have to determine in NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification *which* attributes had changed? I am not sure I am going to be able to do this since the userinfo in the notification contains only the newly saved values.

Comment: On one occasion, yes. It was a lot more work. I listened for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification`, because I could create a second managed object context where the changes hadn't been saved yet. Then I could go through two different contexts (the one I was observing and the new one) looking for differences. The `insertedObjects`, `updatedObjects`, and `deletedObjects` methods help here, but it's still kind of a lot of work.